# Is there a way to get an asyncio.create_task to return a value outside of an async function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I need a value to be returned from an asyncio.create_task(function()) outside of an async function.

```py
import asyncio

async def hello():
    return("hello")

response = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(hello())
print(response)
```

This is what is outputted:

```py
<Task pending coro=<hello() running at C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\PCWebsite\fjdfjd.py:3>>
```

When I want to receive:

```py
"Hello"
```

Note that I cannot use .run()

```py
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

Or run_until_complete as I receive the error

```py
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) documentation the function return a `Task` object.

> #### asyncio.create_task(coro, *, name=None)
>
> Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and schedule its execution. Return
>   the Task object.

You can use the [Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) functions to extract the results (and some other information) from the task itself by calling the function `task.result()` when the results are ready (the task is done).

Example:

```
import asyncio

async def func1():
    return 1233

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(func1())
# The following line is needed so the loop will run and complete the task in the first place.
loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

Result with:

```
>>> task.done()
True
>>> task.result()
1233
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are running this code from a jupyter notebook, in a new cell, you can simply do:

```
await hello()
```

Since event loop is already running, you don't need to worry about getting the event loop.
In case you are running it on terminal, you should do:

```
asyncio.run(hello())
```

Comment: That's not an answer to the question that M_M stated.